# Permutation of Matrices on a Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> We have the following two matrices:
> $A=\left( \begin{matrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right)$ and $B=\left( \begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{matrix} \right).$ Take any finite product of them and multiply this by the vector $x=\left<1,1\right>$. What possible vectors $(x',y')$ can we get?

E.g. $ABx=\left<3,2 \right>$.

Comment: Are matrix inverses authorized?

Comment: No. You can't use inverses.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Call $S$ the set of vectors $(p,q)$ such that $(p,q)$ can be obtained from an arbitrary product of $A$ and $B$, multiplied by $(1,1)$. For convenience, to avoid writing transpose vectors everywhere, I write $(p,q)$ for the column vector.

**If $(p,q)$ is possible, $p$ and $q$ are coprime.**

Proof: we start initially with $(1,1)$, and $1$ is coprime to $1$. For any $(p,q)\in S$, we can write $(p,q)=M_nM_{n-1}\cdots M_1 (1,1)$ with $M_i=A$ or $M_i=B$. Now, by induction, if $(u,v)$ are coprime, then $M_i (u,v)=(u',v')$, and either:

- $u'=u+v$, $v'=v$ and $(u',v')$ are coprime,
- $u'=u$, $v'=u+v$ and again $(u',v')$ are coprime.

And since the initial values $(1,1)$ are coprime, so are $(p,q)$, by induction.

Therefore, for all $(p,q)\in S$, $p$ and $q$ are coprime.

**If $p$ and $q$ are coprime, then $(p,q)$ is possible.**

To see why, we will build a decreasing sequence $(u_i,v_i)$ such that if $(u_i,v_i)$ is possible, then so is $(p,q)$. If we can prove the sequence ends with $(1,1)$, we are done.

Let's start from a given $(p,q)$ with coprime $p,q$.

If $(u-v,v)$ is possible, then $A(u-v,v)=(u,v)$ is possible. Likewise, if $(u,v-u)$ is possible, $B(u,v-u)=(u,v)$ is possible.

We start the sequence with $u_0=p, v_0=q$. At each step $i$, $u_i$ and $v_i$ are positive and coprime (hence different, unles they are both equal to $1$).

If $u_i=v_i$, then $u_i=v_i=1$ (they are coprime) and we are done: we can rewrite the sequence as a product $M_0M_{1}\cdots M_{n-1}(1,1)$.

Otherwise, either $u_i>v_i$ or $u_i<v_i$.

If $u_i>v_i$, let $(u_{i+1},v_{i+1})=(u_i-v_i,v_i)$. And if $u_i<v_i$, let $(u_{i+1},v_{i+1})=(u_i,v_i-u_i)$. Thus, either way, $(u_{i},v_{i})=A(u_{i+1},v_{i+1})$ or $(u_{i},v_{i})=B(u_{i+1},v_{i+1})$. That is, $(u_{i},v_{i})=M_i(u_{i+1},v_{i+1})$ with $M_i=A$ or $M_i=B$.

Since $u_i$ and $v_i$ are positive and coprime, then so are $u_{i+1}$ and $v_{i+1}$, and $0<u_{i+1}+v_{i+1}<u_i+v_i$. Since we have a strictly decreasing sequence $s_i=u_i+v_i$ of positive numbers, it must stop at some point, and it can only stop if $u_n=v_n=1$ for some $n$.

Then, $(p,q)=(u_0,v_0)=M_0M_1\cdots M_{n-1}(1,1)$.

Therefore, if $p$ and $q$ are positive and coprime, then $(p,q)\in S$.

---

All in all, $S$ is the set of pairs of positive coprime integers.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by showing that
$$A^n = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & n\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},\quad B^m = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
m & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then,
$$A^nB^m = \begin{bmatrix}
1+nm & n\\
m & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$A^nB^m x = \begin{bmatrix}
1+(1+m)n\\
1+m \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Good start. But note that $AB\ne BA$, so there are more possibilities.

Comment: That's correct if all the A's are together and if all the B's are together, but the question asked about any permutation. For example, what if it was ABABABABx?

Comment: @ZixunTau $(AB)^n=\begin{pmatrix} F_{2n+1} & F_{2n} \\ F_{2n} & F_{2n-1}\end{pmatrix}$ where $F_n$ are Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Nice! Not too hard to prove via induction. How would that help you if there are not repeating matrices. For example, what about AABABBBAA?

Comment: I don't think I can improve my answer.  The question seems too general to furnish an answer that is formulaic.  Maybe someone else can share something more insightful.